# Analog sound data

Tags: analog, sensor, adc, sound, pulldown

I tried to make my own sound sensor on a PCB. I wanted to take analog sound data for my project. I used an ADC pin from a STM32G474, but I maded mistake while I designing. I took a KY-038 reference schematic from this link:

[image]

https://easyeda.com/editor#id=7189f5cb17f041c48c57c5e5daaec42e

[image]

PROBLEM:

My mistake is I didn't put R2 100k pull-down resistor. Moreover, I didn't put VR1 100K potentiometer. I thought it was not necessary. After soldering I tried to wake it up but it doesn't work.

This was the result on the serial port:

[image]

What can I do? Can anyone help me solve this problem?

My design:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: As you have found out you need those components so put them in.

Comment: Your question is rather confusing. What do you exactly understand as sound sensor? What should it sense in which form ? Why did you delete random components from a project and left others ? Why are you showing a layout and 3d view from *yet* another project? Please clarify those points before expecting a sensible answer.

Comment: I see U1 in your schematic and U9 on your PCB.  Are they the same part?  Also, resistor numbers on the PCB that don't correspond to anything on the schematic.  Are these the same project?  Why do you only post part of the PCB image?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the datasheet of the chip you used https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/lm393-d.pdf
You'll find out this is a *comparator* which takes 2 analog voltages and outputs one digital one. You then can't get the analog signal from of this.

For a signal that you can sample with your ADC, you'll want to use a circuit with a analog output instead, like the one on the [GY-MAX4466](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-MAX4466-Electret-Mic-Amplifier-PCBs) (also available on ebay for cheaper) based on the chip with the same name: [datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/MAX4465-MAX4469.pdf)